# Mozilla randomly removes table borders when printing

Tags: html, css, printing, mozilla

I need to print a page containing a large table with borders (collapsed). Mozilla seems to remove some of the borders at random in the print window. Not only on the edges, but also borders inside the table (cell borders). I tried adjusting the page margins for printing and that seems to change which borders are deleted, but I wasn't able to find any combination of margins that displays all borders.

Meanwhile, Google Chrome prints everything flawlessly. Is there anything I can do about this?

Edit: I would like to mention that in Mozilla, the borders are displayed correctly before print. This only happens when trying to print the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of this occurring when border-collapse is set to collapse or separate. You may need to enact a print-only style to correct this for mozilla.

I cannot help you any further without your code. To get better answers check out this article:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

```css
@media print {
    table{
      border-collapse: unset;
    }
}
```